# Android Debug Bridge and german keyboard

Tags: android, adb

I have my Asus Tablet connected via USB and I´m able to send char with adb.

But I cant find key codes for a german keyboard. How can I send characters like ä, ö, ü usw.

I´m able to place these chars over softkeyboard so I there has to be a keycode for those keys.

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though someone has created a GitHub project for this very issue:

https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard